# Eclipse cannot read React JSX syntaxt

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, jsx

My situation is the following: 
I have a Spring boot application (Maven build tool) with java and i want to incorporate ReactJs as the frontend. I created the webpack with - 
`npx create-react-app somename` inside the folder structure of my Java project:

[image]

and when i start the webpack from the terminal it works properly. However i am trying to understand why multiple errors appear. They look like so:

[image: Inside index.js]

All the errors are of type Javascript and state "semicolon missing" or "expecting different element in this location", but everything is working fine, which leaves me to believe that eclipse just does not validate the JSX correctly.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to get a jsx plugin for eclipse so it knows that it is looking at jsx code and not js

Comment: @PatrickEvans is there any perticular one that i should get?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Wild Web Developer™ works well. https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.wildwebdeveloper

Use version 1.00 as version 1.04 has some issues with tsx files documented here: https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/980#issuecomment-1484535989